# embed youtube video with the 'large player' option

Tags: iframe, video, youtube, embed

I would like to embed a youtube video with the 'large player' and full screen options as seen here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRsV_eUovKw notice just to the left of the full screen option there is a 'large player' option.

Can someone suggest the iframe option to include the 'large player' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look as though there's an option for the large player in embedded YouTube videos right now.  Right clicking on your example video and clicking **Copy embed HTML** gives the following:

```
<iframe width="640" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xRsV_eUovKw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The only parameter this adds is the `allowfullscreen` option.  This renders with the full screen button but nothing for the large player.

After looking at [**Google's documentation**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) on YouTube embedding, it doesn't seem to have any information on the large player either.  My guess is that since you can adjust the size of the player with CSS that Google didn't bother to add the large player as an option for embedded videos.  But who knows, maybe it's a hidden parameter (Google likes to do things like that :) or they'll release it in a future update.